# Android (Xamarin) navigating folder tree through Storage Access Framework Uri

Tags: android, xamarin, uri, storage-access-framework, saf

Attempting to navigate folder tree using Storage Access Framework and Uri, I am seeming some unexpected behavior. In short, my test case is a roundtrip DocumentFile -> Uri -> DocumentFile -> Uri test.
(code is for Xamarin but these are underlying Android classes so it should not be language specific.)

```
void Test(DocumentFile folder)
{
  var uri = folder.Uri;
  //
  // Test case is using an SD card mounted in a card trader in a USB hub.
  // uri: {content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1111-1111%3ADCIM/document/1111-1111%3ADCIM%2F110ND810}
  //
  var folder2 = DocumentFile.FromTreeUri(context, uri);
  var uri2 = folder2.Uri;
  //
  // uri2: {content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1111-1111%3ADCIM/document/1111-1111%3ADCIM}
  //
  // At this point I expected uri2 to be equal to uri, but it's not.
  // Instead, uri2 points to the parent of uri
  //
}
```

Question 1: Are my expectations off here? Should I not expect to be able to navigate a SAF folder tree using Uri?

Question 2: If so, what is a suitable workaround?

Comment: Hi , about External storage , you can have a look at this doc . (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 0):

The following library makes working with SAF so easy. I think you shouldn't get two different uri!

https://github.com/madnik7/PortableStorage